# Most efficient 3d engine for android?

Tags: android, c++, c, 3d-engine

I'm looking for convenient and efficient 3d engine for android. Can you recommend me one om them? Now I choose [ShiVa3D](http://www.stonetrip.com/), but I'm really concerned about performance, because I'm writing augmented reality application, which definitely needs all CPU resources =).

All what I need from 3d engine are:

- load model (scene) imported from 3dmax
- render basic animation
- playing audio
- load C++ modules (my external lib with frame processing)
- maybe (not mandatory!) basic physic

So I looking for light convenient 3d engine for android =) Or performance differences are not significant?

Comment: Find small doc with some explanation and comparison http://flexmappers.com/img/3D_Engines_for_iOS_Development_01.12.PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity3D should cover all your needs. It's light, convenient and easy to learn.

Shiva also has those qualities, but is not as easy and convenient as Unity. It has the added benefit of not requiring a $400 license to publish to Android.

The other options are probably too cumbersome for what you need.

Performance-wise, I don't think there's much of a difference. The burden is more on you of optimizing the poly counts, textures, and code.

Bottom-line, I think Unity will probably save you time, Shiva will probably same you some money. So your mileage may vary. Unity3D has an Android trial you can use to test it and compare

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the developers of [Linderdaum Engine](http://www.linderdaum.com) and would recommend you using it. It is open source. It runs on Windows and Android, so you can do all you prototyping on Windows. It can:

- load animated .md5 models exported from 3dsmax
- render skeletal animations
- playing .ogg and tracker (.xm, .it - very handy on mobile devices)
  audio
- has integrated Box2D physics

And you can easily load your C++ modules in it.